# Injecting JavaScript to PDF from MVC 3 controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, acrobat-sdk

In my `ASP.NET MVC3(Razor)` application am struggling with the `print utility`. I want to `auto print a PDF file which is converted from rdlc`.

I converted the rdlc to pdf using the following code:

```
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();

        localReport.ReportPath = @"Reports/OP/Rdlc/ClinicInvoiceReceipt.rdlc";

        iClinicInvoiceReceipt = new RmtOPInvoice.ClinicInvoiceReceipt();
        DataTable dt = iClinicInvoiceReceipt.SelectReceiptDtlForPrint(1);

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = dt;
        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        string reportType = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        string deviceInfo =
         @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>5.83in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>8.27in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;

        string[] streams;

        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
           reportType,
           deviceInfo,
           out mimeType,
           out encoding,
           out fileNameExtension,
           out streams,
           out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, "application/pdf");
```

I want to display this on view at the same time want to `open the print dialog of pdf viewer automaticaly`

I just here about putting javscript to pdf [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf). But am confused of achieving this in my above code. If anybody gone through this please share . That will be really helpful for me.

I just found out the same scenario is done in PHP. [Here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php) .

Comment: You don't have that much control over how a web browser (or PDF plugin) operates.

Comment: that reference for is an Acrobat specific implementation - which is considered a security risk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i achieved this using `iTextSharp`

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/569335/Automatically-Printing-an-RDLC-file-in-ASP-NET-MVC) is the sample project i did.

Comment: why -ve voting. I am ready to prove that... Please do comment what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this answer I found is helpful

1. It is ASP.NET MVC
2. It is Directly streaming the RDLC response

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/11/25/rendering-an-rdlc-directly-to-the-response-stream-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx